# How can I make tikz daw a curve around the perimeter of a diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

With the following code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.05,shorten >=0.25pt,node distance=1.4cm,on grid,auto] 
        \node[state,initial] (A)   {$A$}; 
        \node[state] (B) [right=of A] {$B$}; 
        \node[state] (C) [below right=of B] {$C$}; 
        \node[state] (D) [above right=of C] {$D$}; 
        \node[state] (E) [above right=of B] {$E$}; 
        \node[state] (F) [right=of D] {$F$}; 
        \path[->] 
        (A) edge node {$\epsilon$} (B)
        (B) edge node {1} (C)
        (B) edge node {0} (E)
        (C) edge node {$\e$} (D)
        (E) edge node {$\e$} (D)
        (D) edge node {$\e$} (F)
        (A) edge node {$\epsilon$} (B)
        (F) edge [bend left=120] node {$\epsilon$} (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I produce the following graph:

[image]

I use bend-right to try and send an arrow from $F$ to $A$, but the arrow cuts past $C$ (and luatex complains that "Dimension too large").

I was hoping to achieve something similar to the yellow arrows on the following graph from $g$ to $s$:

[image]

What should I try?

Comment: Can you please expand your code snippet to a minimal working example. That is, the smallest piece of *compilable code*, starting with a `\documentclass` command and that includes all necessary packages (and no others), that demonstrates your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is use of `scale=0.05`. just remove it (its purpose is not clear) and image will become as you like to have:

[image]

with use of `quotes` library your code snippet can be written as mwe as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance=15mm, on grid]
\node[state,initial] (A)   {$A$};
\node[state] (B) [right=of A] {$B$};
\node[state] (C) [below right=of B] {$C$};
\node[state] (D) [above right=of C] {$D$};
\node[state] (E) [above right=of B] {$E$};
\node[state] (F) [right=of D] {$F$};
%
\path[->]   (A) edge ["$\epsilon$"] (B)
        (B) edge ["1" '] (C)
        (B) edge ["0"] (E)
        (C) edge ["$\epsilon$" '] (D)
        (E) edge ["$\epsilon$"] (D)
        (D) edge ["$\epsilon$"] (F)
        (A) edge ["$\epsilon$"] (B)
        (F) edge [bend left=90,"$\epsilon$"] (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```